# Possible to drop NA geomType in readOGR?

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, rgdal

I have a `gdb` file which is giving me trouble.

```
f = '/path/to/folder.gdb'
layers = ogrListLayers(f)
geom_list = lapply(layers, readOGR, dsn = f)
```

Gives an error on one of the layers:

> Source: "f", layer: "troubleLayer"
>
> Error in ogrInfo(...): Multiple incompatible geometries: wkbPolygon: 110284, NA: 493

It appears that some of the contained polygons are corrupted... I thought the `require_geomType` argument would fix this but alas:

```
readOGR(f, 'troubleLayer', require_geomType = 'wkbPolygon')
```

Gives a completely unexpected output:

> Warning message in readOGR(...) : "eType not chosen"
>
> [ repeat this message hundreds of times]
>
> NOTE: keeping only NA wkbPolygon of 110777 features
>
> Error: length(srl) > 0 is not TRUE

Is it possible to simply drop the apparent `NA` geometries and load this gdb into R?

Comment: Have you tried reading it with the `sf` package and `st_read`? That will either work, in which case you can convert to `sp` with `as(X, "Spatial")` or fail, possibly with a more useful error message....

Comment: @MichaelChirico Were you ever able to solve this? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: sorry @jospehwb but I don't recall solving the issue. that said, `@Spacedman` gives the right advice as rgdal & kin are on the road to deprecation.